# Paypal Adaptive

Tags: paypal, payment

I am using paypal adaptive. Its working if i use sandbox account. But paypal is not working if i use live account.

Paypal throw error as below.

> Array
>           (Server: Apache
>       X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-ID: 15674515-0c90-a115-45a6-9f3dfffd5017!AdaptivePayments!10.17.84.90![]
>       X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.0.0
>       X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-NAME: {http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap}AdaptivePayments
>       X-PAYPAL-API-RC: 580029
>       X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV
>       X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: Preapproval
>       CACHE-CONTROL: no-cache
>       X-PAYPAL-ERROR-RESPONSE: TRUE
>       X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL: NONE
>       Vary: Accept-Encoding
>       HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: dcg12.slc
>       Paypal-Debug-Id: 29d4c08e5ad57
>       Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER] => name=LIVE6.APIT.1&silo_version=880&app=adaptivepaymentspartaweb_api3t&TIME=3709250391&HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR=dcg12.slc;
>   Expires=Wed, 10 Aug 2016 12:28:21 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/;
>   Secure; HttpOnly
>       Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
>       Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>       Pragma: no-cache
>       Connection: close
>       Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

In this error, its showing like missing some subscription parameter. But I could not find what parameter is missing. Since its working correctly in sandbox.

```
responseEnvelope.timestamp=2016-08-10T04:58:21.486-07:00
[responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
[responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 29d4c08e5ad57
[responseEnvelope.build] => 24003818
[error(0).errorId] => 580029
[error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
[error(0).subdomain] => Application
[error(0).severity] => Error
[error(0).category] => Application
[error(0).message] => One of the required parameters for subscription is missing
[error(0).parameter(0)] => Subscription
)
```

Kindly check and give me the solution.